# Connecting to sharepoint from android

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, login

We have SharePoint installed on our 2008 SBS server and I can access this using my desktop from address `http://companyweb` which redirects to `http://companyweb/default.aspx` and works fine.  However, when I type `"http://companyweb"` on my android device it searches the internet. If I type `http://companyweb.domain.local` the default IIS7 homepage is displayed.  How can i get the login to sharepoint on my android device?

I wasn't sure whether to post this here or Android but I thought the solution might be getting the correct SharePoint URL.  Please forward me to a more appropriate place if you feel this is right.

Thanks

Comment: Internet works.  It might be a dns issue. How do i get SharePoints full URL? i know the ip address of the server, what would i type after that to access the sharepoint server address?

Comment: I think I've realized the problem now. Apple and Windows desktop both use my companies DNS suffix (domain.local) and android doesn't. If I use the FQDN (fully qualified domain name) Windows servers IIS doesn't redirect to SharePoint.  How can I find the full path for sharepoint on my server?

Answer (score 2):

> Mobile browser redirection To access a site using the optimized mobile
>   browser experience, a new feature named Mobile Browser Viewer must be
>   activated on the site. If activated, this feature checks the device’s
>   mobile browser to determine if it can handle HTML5. If the mobile
>   browser supports HTML5 the contemporary view is shown. Otherwise, the
>   classic view is shown.
>
> By default, this feature is activated when any of the following site
>   templates are used:
>
> Collaboration templates    Team Site, Blank Site, Document Workspace,
>   Blog, Group Work Site, Visio Process Repository
>
> Meetings templates    Basic Meeting Workspace, Blank Meeting
>   Workspace, Decision Meeting Workspace, Social Meeting Workspace,
>   Multipage Meeting Workspace
>
> Enterprise templates    Document Center, Records Center, Business
>   Intelligence Center, My Site Host, Basic Search Center, FAST Search
>   Center
>
> All other site templates require you to explicitly activate the
>   feature. You can activate or deactivate Mobile Browser Viewer in Site
>   Settings under Site Actions and Manage Site Features.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/use-a-mobile-device-to-work-with-sharepoint-online-sites-HA102891452.aspx#_Toc351995396

a more detailed info on the redirection feature follow:

**legacy MobileRedirection feature**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462572(v=office.14).aspx

**EDIT**

Your right android uses FQDN and not dns suffix hence why your getting the login issue,

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20419/how-can-i-enable-dns-suffix-support-on-android-resolv-conf-search

I think this becomes more of an android issue rather than a sharepoint issue

> Does anybody know if there is any workaround on this? (without having
>   to root the device). Is there any way to configure the device or
>   browser to always interpret or modify a given address to its FQDN
>   form? I use Sharepoint, and I can use the FQDN address with no
>   problem, but as soon as the server redirect me, the browser stop
>   finding the server.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8030

you could try this, you need to add alternate access mapping for fdqn as android has no dns suffix

> By default, a new SharePoint Server 2013 deployment enables access
>   through the NetBIOS name (e.g., savdalsps01) and not its FQDN (e.g.,
>   savdalsps01.savilltech.net). To solve the problem, an Alternate Access
>   Mapping must be added for the FQDN.
>
> 1.Navigate to the SharePoint Server 2013 Central Administration site (e.g., http://:6999, e.g.,
>   `http://savdalsps01:6999`).
>
> 2.Select System Settings from the navigation pane.
>
> 3.Under Farm Management, select the Configure alternate access mappings.
>
> 4.Under Alternate Access Mapping Collection, select Change Alternate Access Mapping Collection.
>
> 5.Select name of SharePoint - 80.
>
> 6.Click the Add Internal URLs link.
>
> 7.Type the FQDN `http://<FQDN>:80` (e.g., `http://savdalsps01.savilltech.net:80`) and select the Intranet Zone
>   from the drop down and select Save.

i know its for 2013 but is same for 2010

http://windowsitpro.com/sharepoint-2013/enable-fqdn-access-sharepoint-2013

Comment: The article says to type in the URL.  My problem is the url from android isn't working.  How can i get the url to work?

Comment: @resolver101: do you mean you can't edit / alter the URL in your mobile browser?

Comment: no i mean.  Why does the url work from desktop and iphone but not from android.  I want it to work from android.

Comment: @resolver101 androdi blocks sharpeoint popup for some reason to login, try this, goto android app store and download the firefox browser app and access site from there! it should work fine!

Comment: im using firfox for my testing

Comment: just ammended my answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct URL https://remote.companyname.co.uk:987/default.aspx.  This works on all platforms.  Thanks for all your help :-)